# Ubuntu 18.04 Stuck in started hold until boot process finishes up

Tags: boot, 18.04

I restarted my computer and now it’s stuck on `started hold until boot process finishes up.`
I’ve seen some threads that say to free up some space. If I do that will I lose my data?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What was your solution?